# Mean time spent on tasks in Jira

Tags: jira

I'm new to Jira so maybe my question is trivial. I need to get a statistics about a whole team and individual members. Currently I'm mostly interested in a mean time a person spends on a task (all our tasks have similar complexity).

How can I get this information in Jira? (Currently we don't arrrange sprints, we just create tasks and assign them to developers.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your filters you can show the attribute "Time spent" as column. Click on the top right on "Columns" and search for this attribute to enable it on your filter list.

Furthermore you can add Gadgets to your Dashboards. I see two gadgets here:

- Resolution Time
- Time Since Chart

Comment: Thank  you! I did as you said. But I didn't get all the tasks and sub-tasks. A lot of tasks are sub-tasks marked with "a green circle with a tick" (I suppose these are closed or pending tasks?) - these ones are missing from the results. What should I do to include them in the results (and see their "Time spent")?

Comment: You can define your filter on the top text area. If you want to see all of your tickets of one project, you can e.g. write a filter like `project = yourProject`.

Comment: What I did is: 1. selected my project in a drop-down list of projects 2, assignee = a team member 3. Type = All 4. Status = All. And I don't get all the (sub-)tasks. The missing (sub-)tasks are ones marked with a green circle with a tick. What's wrong?

Comment: Click on your project, click on `Overview` -> `Issues`. Then click on `All Issues`. Now you see all issues and a text area on top with a filter `project = yourProject`. Now you can e.g. add your assignee filter: `project = yourProject AND assignee = yourTeamMember`. Now you see all tickets of yourProject of yourTeamMember (no matter which type).